# Model Binding Error for Parent Object Entity

Tags: asp.net-core

Using latest ASP.NET Core, Windows 10 Pro

TLDR: my controller is returning a "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelError" for an entity's parent.

Entity: Schedule

```
public class Schedule
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ScheduleId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Start On")]
    public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);

    [Display(Name = "Reschedule On")]
    public string Recurrence { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Parameter 1")]
    [MaxLength(256), StringLength(256)]
    public string Param1 { get; set; }

    // ... more properties

    [Display(Name = "Parameter 7")]
    [MaxLength(256), StringLength(256)]
    public string Param7 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Message Text")]
    public string MessageText { get; set; }

    #region relationships

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "For Process")]
    public int ProcessId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "For Process")]
    public virtual Process Process { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ScheduleNotification> ScheduleNotifications { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

Entity: Process

```
public class Process : IValidatableObject
{
    private int? _ApplicationId;

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int ProcessId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(80, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "Names must be between 5 and 80 characters")]
    [MaxLength(80)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Process Type")]
    public ProcessTypeEnum ProcessType { get; set; }

    // ... more properties

    [Display(Name = "Primary Application")]
    public int? ApplicationId
    {
        get
        {
            return _ApplicationId;
        }
        set
        {
            _ApplicationId = value == 0 ? null : value;
        }
    }

    public Application Application { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Schedule> Schedules { get; set; }
}
```

Controller Action on Create Get

```
public IActionResult Create(int? processId)
{
    // no value provided, so redirect to view that prompts for process
    if (!processId.HasValue || processId == 0)
    {
        TempData["Error"] = "You must select a process to schedule";
        return RedirectToAction("Processes");
    }

    var schedule = new Schedule()
    {
        ProcessId = processId.GetValueOrDefault(),
        Process = _context.Processes.Find(processId.GetValueOrDefault()),
        ScheduleNotifications = new List<ScheduleNotification>()
    };

    return View(schedule);
}
```

Razor view called on create

```
@model HangfireServer.Models.Schedule

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Schedule</h1>

<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

            <div class="text-danger" style="direction:rtl" asp-validation-summary="All"></div>

            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ProcessId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Process)

            <div class="form-group row">
                <text class="control-label col-sm-2">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Process.Name)</text>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Process.Name)
                </div>
                <text class="text-left col-sm-6 text-secondary">Process to schedule</text>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label asp-for="StartDateTime" class="control-label col-sm-2"></label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input asp-for="StartDateTime" class="control-label" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="StartDateTime" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <text class="text-left col-sm-6 text-secondary">Date and time to initiate process</text>
            </div>

            <!-- more stuff -->>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Create post controller

```
// POST: Schedules/Create
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ScheduleId,StartDateTime,Recurrence,Param1,Param2,Param3,Param4,Param5,Param6,Param7,ProcessId,Process,ScheduleNotifications")] Schedule schedule)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // save the new schedule
        schedule.Process = await _context.Processes.FindAsync(schedule.ProcessId);
        _context.Add(schedule);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        // queue the new schedule
        EnqueueProcess(schedule);
        TempData["Success"] = $"Process {schedule.Process.Name} has been scheduled";


        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    // display additional errors not caught in page validation

    string errorMessage = "";

    foreach (var modelState in ViewData.ModelState.Values)
    {
        foreach (var error in modelState.Errors)
        {
            errorMessage = String.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage) ? error.ToString() : "<br>" + error.ToString();
        }
    }

    TempData["Error"] = errorMessage;

    // return to current view
    return RedirectToAction("Create", new { processId = schedule.ProcessId });
}
```

On trace, the GET is passing to the view schedule with its parent process id and process object populated. On POST

1. ModelState.IsValid = False
2. schedule.processId = 2 (or whatever the value sent from GET was
3. schedule.process is null (even though there's a hidden field for process in vie)
4. ModelState only has 1 invalid key

SubKey={Process}, Key="Process", ValidationState=Invalid

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out - but this is just a hack, there's probably a correct way to do it

// populate process property with an instance of a process object
schedule.Process = await _context.Processes.Include(p => p.Application).FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.ProcessId == schedule.ProcessId);
ModelState.Clear();

Then either
ModelState.Remove("Process");

Or
TryValidateModel(schedule);

Regardless ModelState.IsValid is now true